# Need Help Creating New Connection Using Oracle SQL Developer 3.2 with Oracle Database 11G 2 Release

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I have Windows 7 Home Premium (64bit)
I tried installing and uninstalling Oracle Database XE and everytime I am installing it I run into two error message. The first eroor message tell me that a file something like file C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Temp{9D21B7C5-5DF8-450-B84A-48908DFACA7F}\ and when i click on it twice it goes away and the installation finishes but then when i try running oracle database xe it tell me that http:\127.0.0.1%HTTPPORT%\apex\f?p=4950 cant be found or something. I dont know what to do. Also, once igve gotten past these problems and fixed them how do i proceed to create a database. That is my final goal to create a database using oracle sql developer and oracle database xe to start creating tables and querying. Id appreciate it if you could help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you and i solved it taking the steps below:

1. With the error message box still open, click the Windows start button and type “regedit” in the search box. Press enter. The registry editor will open.
2. On the left column, expand the folders as follows: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT -> Installer -> Products -> 266B7A….. -> SourceList-> Media
3. Look for ’1′ under Name on the right column. Under ‘Data’ on the same row, the value should be ‘DISK 1′ or something similar. Right click on that row and click on ‘Modify’.
4. A window named ‘Edit String’ will open and type in the address indicated in the error window you had from the Oracle installer, ending just before ‘KEY_XE.reg’. It should end with a row of numbers/letters then ‘}\”.
5. Click OK and close the Registry Editor.
6. Return to the Oracle Installer and click OK on the error message box.
7. It will take a while, but eventually, the installer will indicate that installation is complete.
8. To check if everything’s good, click on the windows start button -> All programs -> Oracle Database 11g Express Edition -> Get started.
9. A web browser will appear and the Oracle Database Get Started page will load.

   Hope it helps you!